# Restkit to-many relationship append to set instead of setting a new set

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit, object-object-mapping

I have a iOS Restkit related question. I have a parent-child relationship data coming from a remote server and map those object to a `NSManagedObject` object with Restkit. The problem that I am currently having is every request to the server always wipe out the "child" relationship and replace it with the new data coming from the server. Is there a way to avoid those and append the new child instead?

For example: I have a classic Category --> Products relationship.

> ```
> {"categories": [
>     {
>         "cat_id": "1",
>         "cat_title": "category 1",
>         "cat_tag": 1,
>         "product": [
>             {
>                 "prod_id": "1",
>                 "prod_name": "product 1",
>                 "prod_tag": 1
>             },
>             {
>                 "prod_id": "2",
>                 "prod_name": "product 2",
>                 "prod_tag": 1
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> ] }
> ```

And that works fine and everything is saved properly with the relationship on the CoreData. But if I make another request to the server and have a new response:

> ```
> {"categories": [
>     {
>         "cat_id": "1",
>         "cat_title": "category 1",
>         "cat_tag": 1,
>         "product": [
>             {
>                 "prod_id": "3",
>                 "prod_name": "product 3",
>                 "prod_tag": 1
>             },
>             {
>                 "prod_id": "4",
>                 "prod_name": "product 4",
>                 "prod_tag": 1
>             }
>         ]
>     }
> ] }
> ```

I will have product 3 and product 4 replace product 1 and product 2 on the database. I am sure I setup all the relationship and primary key correctly. (Both `cat_id` and `prod_id` are set as a primary key).

Having investigated through the RestKit's internal framework, I noticed that around `line 576` in the `RKObjectMappingOperation` class, there is

> ```
> RKLogTrace(@"Mapped NSSet relationship object from keyPath '%@' to
>            '%@'. Value: %@", relationshipMapping.sourceKeyPath,
>            relationshipMapping.destinationKeyPath, destinationObject);
>
> NSMutableSet *destinationSet = [self.destinationObject
>                          mutableSetValueForKey:relationshipMapping.destinationKeyPath];
> [destinationSet setSet:destinationObject];
> ```

So I guess that is easy to just change

`[destinationSet setSet:destinationObject];`

to

`[destinationSet addObjectsFromArray:[destinationObject allObjects]]`

But I was wondering whether there is a better way to do it?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the support from `Reskit`. It is now supported by `RKRelationshipMapping`.(https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/989)

Just set `assignmentPolicy` value of `RKRelationshipMapping` instance to `RKUnionAssignmentPolicy`