# Restkit mapping one to many

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have mapping like this:

```
RKObjectMapping *pageMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[pageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"rows, columns", @"header", @"size", @"backgroundColor" ]];

RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"content", @"crop", @"fontName", @"fontSize", @"height", @"width",
 @"paddingLeft", @"paddingTop", @"paddingRight", @"paddingBottom", @"src", @"textColor", @"type", @"url", @"posX", @"posY" ]];

[objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"objects" toKeyPath:@"objects" withMapping:pageMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:pageMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"pages" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:[magazine contentPath]
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              [self sortPageResult];
                                              Page *page = (Page *)[self.pagesFetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
                                              NSLog(@"%d", [[page objects] count]);

                                              //[self changeStatusToDownloaded:[magazine magazineID]];
                                              [self.collectionView reloadData];
                                          } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              [self displayError];
                                              NSLog(@"Product error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                              [self.collectionView reloadData];
                                          }];
```

And I've got a problem with mapping. I clearly map "page" object, but I can't map "object". When I try it I get something like this:

```
Relationship 'objects' fault on managed object (0x1d8b57a0) <Page: 0x1d8b57a0> (entity: Page; id: 0x1d8b0740 <x-coredata://30A44191-D972-4222-88DF-539C2875F293/Page/p1> ; data: {
backgroundColor = FFFFFF;
columns = 0;
content = nil;
header = 1;
link = nil;
magazine = nil;
margin = 0;
objects = "<relationship fault: 0x1d8aea40 'objects'>";
pageID = nil;
rows = 0;
size = 1;
})
```

Thx for reply!

Comment: It seems when RESTKIT maps data for first time there's no "object" object. Then when I get it from Core Data, I get error like <relationship fault: 0x1d8aea40 'objects'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New progress

I've changed:

```
[objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"objects" toKeyPath:@"objects" withMapping:pageMapping]];
```

instead:

```
[pageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"items" toKeyPath:@"items" withMapping:itemMapping]];
```

Now is mapping right, but mapping causing duplicating "object" entities. There's only one object, which is remaking again and again :/

Comment: Just set assignmentPolicy value of RKRelationshipMapping instance to RKUnionAssignmentPolicy. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229767/restkit-to-many-relationship-append-to-set-instead-of-setting-a-new-set/14435948#14435948